# Text comparison using explicit intent in Android

Tags: java, android, string-comparison

The output is always `not a girl`. How do I compare the string amruta?

Plz tell me if the statement is fine.

I have used explicit intents and want to compare 2 strings.

Even if I enter "amruta" in editText field, I get `not a girl`.

```
package com.satish.explicitintents;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(Main.this, Second.class); 
                intent.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext")== "amruta")
        {
            tv.setText("girl");
        }
        else 
            tv.setText("not a girl");
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings should be compared using `equals()` method. Please search, this question has been asked at-least 100 times :)

Comment: use equals for string comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `equals()` method instead of `==` operator as below...

```
if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext").equals( "amruta")) {

    tv.setText("girl");

} else {

    tv.setText("not a girl");

}
```

You can also use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method.

Instances of `String` are objects, so you can't compare two objects with `==` operator. The `==` operator is used to compare to primitive type data. To compare two `String`, you have to use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `==` operator in java programming to compare two strings its a bad sign of programming. You need to use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` methods. So use this:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext").equalsIgnoreCase(amruta))
{
   tv.setText("girl");
}
 else {
   tv.setText("not a girl");
}
```